# Frequent Traveller to the UK Does Not Want to Fill Out Landing Cards, Be Interviewed

Tags: visas, uk, visas-on-arrival

A US citizen has been visiting the UK 4 or 5 times a year for either personal or business reasons.  He is tired of the same procedure of filling out a landing card and waiting in the queue for his landing interview.  He doesn't want to do it any more.  He says that the procedure is a meaningless drudgery in his case and may curtail his visits because of this.

Is there any way he can get relief?

Comment: Interesting question. +1

Comment: Asking for a friend

Comment: At least you don't have someone that NEVER smiles, with a gun, just waiting to shoot for any reason they can come up with, you asking you the questions unlike when someone arrives in the USA!

Comment: Fly into Ireland, then fly from Ireland to Heathrow, where you'd exit through Customs but bypass Immigration?

Comment: One might also say, given that UK citizens aren't allowed to enrol for Global Entry, that your friend should be forced to stand in a boring queue each time just like all UK citizens heading westwards are forced to, and they need to lobby their elected representatives to get that fixed! ;-)

Comment: @IanRingrose I thought the CBP officers at the airport didn't carry firearms.  But I never paid much attention, so maybe I'm wrong.  Also, I can't say I've ever had a smile from a UK entry officer, either, or from any other country, come to think of it.

Comment: @Gagravarr Global Entry has been superseded with new automated passport control kiosks, and now anyone who has entered the US at least once since 2008 under the Visa Waiver Program can use the kiosks for future VWP travel, free, no pre-registration required.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Which is great in theory, but in practice I've almost never seen them at the US airport terminals I've flown into :(

Comment: @Gagravarr I understand that they are still being installed, but eventually should be at every US airport with international arrivals, as well as at US preclearance airports. [Here is a current list of airports with APC kiosks.](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/automated-passport-control-apc)

Comment: @phoog I once had a smile (I think) and a farewell like “Have a nice stay” in my language (i.e. that of the country that issued my ID) from the border police in the Netherlands.

Comment: I had the guy in SFX asking if me and my buddy were brothers (when he already had our passports) and then scanning my friends passport and remarking "wow, you lost some weight" after looking at the screen. He had been to Miami 10 years earlier with a different passport. That was creepy, but we al had a good laugh with the immigration officer. He was super chilled. But we waited almost an hour before that.

Comment: @phoog: It depends on the person, but on several occasions I saw that some of the entry officers in China do smile.

Comment: @Relaxed I once got a "welcome home" from a US border officer (despite, or perhaps because of, the fact that I was living in the Netherlands at the time) but I don't think he smiled.  The NL officers were far more likely to look at me quizzically and try to reconcile my Dutch name with my (at various times) US passport, inability to speak Dutch, or non-native accent while soaking Dutch.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

He can apply for the [Registered Traveller service](https://www.gov.uk/registered-traveller):

> Apply for the Registered Traveller service to get through UK border control faster. You won’t need to fill in a landing card.
>
> You can apply if you’re 18 or over and you’re a national of Australia, Canada, Japan, New Zealand or the USA.
>
> One of the following must also be true:
>
> - you’ve got a visa (but not a Tier 5 concession (Creative and sporting), EEA family permit, discretionary leave or leave outside the rules)
> - you’ve visited the UK 4 times in the last 52 weeks eg for business, education, tourism, education or medical treatment
>
> You’ll be able to use the:
>
> - ePassport gates if you have a biometric passport
> - faster entry lanes at Edinburgh, Gatwick, Glasgow, Heathrow, London City, Manchester and Stansted airports, and Brussels, Lille and Paris Eurostar terminals
>
> It costs £70 to apply to use the service for 1 year. If your application is unsuccessful you’ll get £50 back.
>
> If you’re already a member and you get a new passport, you’ll need to pay £20 to update your passport details. Updating your visa information is free.

Comment: is there an explanation for why you have to be a frequent visitor? Most other programs allow the applicants to decide if their travels are frequent enough to make using the program "worth it" and don't require a minimum number of visits.

Comment: My guess is because UK entry requires an interview to decide eligibility on each case; they use successful passes of the interview as a gauge of how likely you are _not_ to abuse your visitation rights.

Comment: @KateGregory I think Burhan Khalid is correct; also note that you don't need to be a frequent visitor if you have a visa.  The frequent visitor requirement therefore prevents those who do not require a visa from being able to enter the UK without ever having been interviewed by a UK official.

Comment: well, I don't need a visa because I'm a Canadian and I only go once or twice a year so I think that means I can't apply. Bummer. I love my Nexus and would be delighted to have a UK equivalent.

Comment: @KateGregory I believe you can still apply for a visa even though you don't need one.  It starts to get expensive, though: it costs £85 to apply plus a fee for the visa itself, which ranges from £324 for a year to £737 for 10 years.  It looks like you could go 4 times in one 52-week period to join, without having to maintain that frequency to keep your membership.

Comment: @KateGregory, they like to refer to 3 interviews in a short period of time as a success/failure point. So presumably with 4 they are comfortable enough to decide the person is OK for at least a year.

Comment: @phoog Sure, you *could* make two extra visits to the UK, but that would cost much more in air fare than just paying for a 10-year visa.

Comment: _you’ve visited the UK 4 times in the last 52 weeks eg for business, **education**, tourism, **education** or medical treatment_ Education is really important.

Comment: @Lohoris: "Education, education, education" https://youtu.be/2kAhChC_qxU

Comment: @DavidRicherby not if you popped across the channel during your two regularly-scheduled trips.

Comment: The rules have just changed: now it's 4 visits in 2 years.

Answer (score 8):

I suppose this question could be put more succinctly as *Does the United Kingdom have a known traveller programme, like ANZ SmartGate or the North American NEXUS/Global Entry?* Indeed, they do: the [Registered Traveller service](https://www.gov.uk/registered-traveller).

Frequent visitors and some visa holders who are adult nationals of Australia, Canada, Japan, New Zealand, and the US can apply. According to the [promotional video](https://gds.blog.gov.uk/2015/02/17/registered-traveller-service-goes-live/), users

> - don't have to fill in landing cards
> - may use faster European Economic Area (EEA) border queues
> - may use ePassport gates at participating UK international ports if they have a biometric passport

Per the website, the express queues are avaialble at Edinburgh, Gatwick, Glasgow, Heathrow, London City, Manchester and Stansted airports, and Brussels, Lille and Paris Eurostar terminals. The annual subscription is £70, though if your application is denied, £50 of that will be refunded.