# Can Egyptian citizen visit Armenia on valid USA visa?

Tags: visas, egyptian-citizens, armenia

We are from Egypt and we are working in Saudi Arabia. Me and my wife also have 5 years  valid USA visa. Travel agent say we don’t need a visa to go to Georgia on valid 5 years USA visa.

Also we want to visit Armenia, is it possible to visit Armenia on valid USA visa ?

Comment: @ahmedmaliki Egypt is listed in those countries who need an invitation for a visa.

Comment: How to get invitation

Comment: you have to look by your own :) try with some travel agents or tour operators

Comment: Please note that "Georgia" is both a state within the USA and a separate, sovereign *country* just north of Armenia. You cannot visit the country of Georgia with a USA visa either - only the state within the USA.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: I thought that too, [but:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Georgia) "*Holders of visas or residence permits of [...] the United States do not require a visa for max 90 days in a 180-day period.*"  So yes, it appears that holding a US visa is enough for Georgia the country to waive their visa requirement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NO. As a Egyptian national even with a valid USA visa or Saudi
 residency, you are not eligible to enter Armenia. Answer is from
 official [Armenia Ministry of foreign
 affairs](http://mfa.am/en/visa/).
Citizens of Egypt are listed who require a visa with invitation only from official ministry of foreign affairs website.

> **Invitations**
>
> You can see the list of countries, citizens of which can obtain
>   Armenian visa only upon invitation and only at the diplomatic
>   representations of consular offices of the Republic of Armenia here.
>
> Armenian nationals who are citizens of those countries can obtain
>   Armenian visa without invitation and upon arrival.
>
> Invitations can be submitted to the Ministry of Foreign Affairs by
>
> a) juridical persons registered in Armenia
>
> b) authorities of Armenia and diplomatic representations or
>   international organizations or their representatives (physical persons
>   submit invitation to the Passport and Visa Department of the Police)

what type and sort of invitation require can be found on this link.

http://www.atb.am/en/tourist/visa/

Also [Visa and Passport](https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/visaform.htm) confirms the same answer from their search engine.

> National Egypt (EG)             /Embarkation Saudi Arabia (SA)
>   Destination Armenia (AM)
>
> **Visa Information**
>
> Armenia (AM)
>
> Passport required.
>   - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be   valid for the period of intended stay.  Passport Exemptions:
>
> - Passengers with an emergency or a temporary passport.
>
> Visa required.
>
> Additional Information:
>
> - Visitors are required to hold proof of sufficient funds to   cover their stay and documents required for their next   destination.

Comment: Using images for text passages like this is less helpful because it hides the text from search engines.  Can you copy and paste the text into your answer?

Comment: @phoog you mean just simply copy the text from website and paste it here?

Comment: That's how I do it when quoting information from gov.uk and other sites.  It usually needs some cleaning up, but I think it's worth the effort.  Also don't forget that the `>` character is supposed to set of quoted material, not your own words.

Comment: Here's an example of an answer of mine.  I was looking for one with more formatting but couldn't find one quickly enough: http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/51200/19400

Comment: @phoog thanks man I always appreciate encouragement :)-